# Event Watching Web3 v1 in Truffle test

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript

I want to test off chain data input in truffle testing.  So basically I kick off a test and then need to wait for another program to do something.  In the old web3, this worked great:

```
function promisifyLogWatch(_event) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _event.watch((error, log) => {
      _event.stopWatching();
      if (error !== null)
        reject(error);
      resolve(log);
    });
    });
}
```

And I test it in my js file like this:

```
await promisifyLogWatch(oracle.NewValue({ fromBlock: 'latest' }));
```

But now I get that _event.watch is not a function.  How do I update this for web3 v1?

Comment: You can probably find your answer [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html?highlight=event#web3-eth-subscribe) or in the vicinity.

Comment: In truffle v5 you have a new api https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64872/truffle-how-to-get-event

Comment: To use contracts directly with web3 v1 here's the api https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pattern I use as well to test Oraclize callback functions. I'm using something like this in a presentation at EthCC next week, so today I had to figure out how to do this in newer versions of Truffle. I ended up doing the following:

```
const getFirstEvent = (_event) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _event.once('data', resolve).once('error', reject)
  });
}
```

I remembered this post from a while back, so I came back to add this as an answer.